# How to add constraint to a colum in MYSQL only to hold values which are already present in another column of same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

**This is the table that I am supposed to create:**

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMtHm.png)

**In `Manager_ID` column I am supposed to add a constraint but I am not sure how to do It**

**This is my code:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE CANDIDATE
(
    Candidate_ID FLOAT(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    Candidate_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Candidate_Email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,
    Candidate_Dept CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'HR',
    Manager_ID VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT CHECK (Candidate_Email LIKE '%@%.%'),
    CONSTRAINT CHECK (Manager_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Candidate_ID FROM CANDIDATE))
);
```

**Can someone help me to add necessary statment to achive above given task.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing CHECK constraints with FOREIGN KEY constraints.  Your second constraint should be a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE CANDIDATE (
    Candidate_ID FLOAT(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    Candidate_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Candidate_Email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,
    Candidate_Dept FLOAT(2) DEFAULT 'HR',
    Manager_ID VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT CHECK (Candidate_Email LIKE '%@%.%'),
    CONSTRAINT fk_candidate_manager_id FOREIGN KEY (Manager_ID) REFERENCES CANDIDATE(Candidate_ID)
);
```

I don't understand this definition:

```
    Candidate_Dept FLOAT(2) DEFAULT 'HR',
```

`'HR'` is not a valid floating point value.  Presumably, you intend a string for that column.  And you should *never* use floating point values for primary keys!

Here is an actually working create table statement that is reasonable:

```
CREATE TABLE CANDIDATE (
    Candidate_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Candidate_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Candidate_Email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,
    Candidate_Dept VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'HR',
    Manager_ID INT,
    CONSTRAINT CHECK (Candidate_Email LIKE '%@%.%'),
    CONSTRAINT fk_candidate_manager_id FOREIGN KEY (Manager_ID) REFERENCES CANDIDATE(Candidate_ID)
);
```

Comment: I didn't knew that foreign key works that way....thankyou very much.

Comment: I am getting error IN MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

Not a `check`, but `foreign key` constraint.

I don't know MySQL syntax; in Oracle, that would be

```
constraint fk_mgr_cand foreign key (manager_id) references candidate (candidate_id)
```

I hope you can apply something similar to MySQL.